# Ignore Ctr+c on program for parent pid

Tags: c, kill, sigint

I'm trying to make my own shell, and I am trying to get Ctrl+c so it closes child processes, but not the father(my_shell).

This is my forking code:

```
 jobs_list[0].pid = fork();
                if (jobs_list[0].pid == 0) {
                        // Child process
                        if (execvp(argumentos[0], argumentos) == -1) {
                                perror("lsh");
                        }
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                } else if (jobs_list[0].pid < 0) {
                        // Error forking
                        perror("lsh");
                } else {
                        while(jobs_list[0].pid  != 0){
                        pause();
                        }
                }
```

So my parent waits for the child, when I hit ctrl+c on a child running, it kills it correctly, but I want to ignore when is my father alone that runs.
My signal handler for ctrl+c is:

```
void ctrlc(int signum) {
            printf("I am the process with PID %d , and the kid process is  %d \n",pid,jobs_list[0].pid);
            if(jobs_list[0].pid > 0){ //when 0 means there is a child
                    printf("I KILL THE PROCESS %d \n",jobs_list[0].pid);
                    kill(jobs_list[0].pid,SIGINT);
                    signal(SIGINT, ctrlc);

            }else{
                    signal(SIGINT, ctrlc);

            }
    }
```

When I have a child sleeping and clikc Ctrl+c:

```
gnadal: ~~>sleep 40
Parse_args()--> token 0: sleep
Parse_args()--> token 1: 40

I am the process with PID 7987 , and the kid process is  7988 
I KILL THE PROCESS 7988
```

But when I am idle I simply get out of the program itself. 
Why my shell stops when I Ctrl+c when on the parent program?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can only safely call async-signal-safe functions from within a signal handler.  `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.

Comment: Just Edited the post itself for a clearer view. But it keeps killing my parent.